# Kentico - Updating an image in the Media Library causes broken links

Tags: kentico

I have an image in the Media Library that I'm using on several different pages.  I'm using the EditableImage and EditableText web parts to link to the image.
When I try to replace the image in the Media Library, using the update link in the Media Library tools, the image links on the pages aren't getting updated.  They still link to the url of the old image, which no longer exists.
It seems to work if the filename is the same, so I assume that the the webpart is only referencing the FilePath of the Media Library image instead of referencing the database record.  Am I using this incorrectly, or is there a better way to include a Media Library image on a page?  When I update an image in the Media Library, I need the links to the image to be updated as well.

I'm working with Kentico v6.0.27 (SP1)‎
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using it correctly and the behavior is correct. You can use "[Use permanent URLs](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/media_library_settings.htm)" setting to change this behavior. It's located at CMSSitemanager->Settings->Content->Media. I have tested it with editable image web part and it works according to your requirements.